# AsyncTaskLoader при повороте экрана

Tags: android

Приложение с помощью AsyncTaskLoader берёт новости из сайта через JSON, вставляет их в RecycleView. Всё сделал - работает. Но есть проблема - при повороте экрана, он снова грузит данные. Чтобы отработать этот момент, переделал через Fragment.

Создал FeedLoader и запустил forceLoad() в методе onCreate во Fragment - чтобы он не запускался каждый раз при повороте.

Почему в RetrieveFeedFragment не срабатывают коллбэки onLoadFinished и другие? Как сделать, чтобы при повороте экрана ничего не менялось, кроме того, что View просто перевернулись?

Неделю не могу сделать уже. Буду благодарен за совет, помощь или подсказку!

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_news"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">
</FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**news_list_fragment**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#dec9c9">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/progressBarLinearLayout">

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/retrieve_feed"
            android:id="@+id/progressBarText"
            android:layout_below="@id/progressBar"
            android:textColor="#164e66"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/listViewNews"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity**

```
RetrieveFeedFragment fragment;;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if(savedInstanceState == null){
        fragment = new RetrieveFeedFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_news, fragment, "retrieve_feed_tag").commit();
        Log.d("myLogs", "New Fragment in Activity");
    }
    else{
        fragment = (RetrieveFeedFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("retrieve_feed_tag");
        Log.d("myLogs", "Get old Fragment by tag in Activity");
    }

}
```

**FeedLoader**

```
public class FeedLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<ArrayList<RSSItemData>>{

    /* Не нагромождаю кодом, вставляю основное */

    public ArrayList<RSSItemData> loadInBackground(){

    /* Парсим данные, возвращаем listData */

    return listData;

    }
}
```

**RetrieveFeedFragment**

```
public class RetrieveFeedFragment extends Fragment
         implements android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<ArrayList<RSSItemData>>{

private RecyclerView rvNews;
LinearLayout progBarLinearLayout;
ProgressBar progBar;
TextView progBarText;
FeedLoader FeedLoader;
RSSAdapter RSSAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
    FeedLoader = new FeedLoader(getActivity());
    FeedLoader.forceLoad();
    Log.d("myLogs", "Fragment onCreate");
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Log.d("myLogs", "Fragment onCreateView");

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_list_fragment, null);

    rvNews = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.listViewNews);
    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    rvNews.setLayoutManager(llm);
    rvNews.setHasFixedSize(true);

    rvNews = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.listViewNews);

    progBarLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.progressBarLinearLayout);
    progBar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    progBarText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.progressBarText);

    return v;

}

@Override
public Loader<ArrayList<RSSItemData>> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<ArrayList<RSSItemData>> loader, ArrayList<RSSItemData> listData) {
    RSSAdapter = new RSSAdapter(listData, getActivity());
    rvNews.setAdapter(RSSAdapter);
    progBarLinearLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<ArrayList<RSSItemData>> loader) {

}


}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю что проверять на null нужно не `savedInstanceState`, а сам фрагмент

Т.е. в методе `onCreate` класса `MainActivity` вместо:

> `if(savedInstanceState == null){ ... }`

сделать:

> `if (fragment == null) { ... }`

---

> Как сделать, чтобы при повороте экрана ничего не менялось, кроме того, что View просто перевернулись?

Можно в файл `manifest.mxl` добавить строку `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` в ваше активити. 
**Но данный способ не рекомендуют использовать как простые разработчики, так и разработчики Android.**

**EDIT:**

используйте метод `setRetainInstance`. Если передать в него true, то при пересоздании фрагмента не будут вызваны методы `onDestroy` и `onCreate`, и не будет создан новый экземпляр класса `Fragment`.

Попробуйте первый способ, в крайнем случае можно использовать второй.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41790/discussion-on-answer-by-mansur-nashaev-asynctaskloader---).